# Missing bar in barchart when using highstock.js instead of highcharts.js

Tags: highcharts

Here is a jsfiddle using the same basic barchart code. With higcharts.js it works but with highstock.js the first bar is missing.

http://jsfiddle.net/LLExL/444/

Notice the first bar for january is missing though the label is there. It's like the whole thing was shifted up until the first bar is off the chart.
I tried chart marginTop, spacingTop and xaxis maxPadding and reverse to work around the issue but all were uneffective.

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug, I reported an issue about it [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/508).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [issue](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/508) is fixed now, in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/CZcKL/) the corresponding dev-version of highstock used instead of the released one (v1.0). Resulting in this chart: [image]

Comment: Thanks for fast response! (PS is the dev version available?)

Comment: Yes we have a public repository on github, here is a direct link to the [latest version](https://raw.github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/stock2/js/highstock.src.js)

Comment: Got:
options is undefined
[Break On This Error] } else if (typeof options[0] === 'number') { // two-dimentional array
highstock.src.js (line 8961)
changed line from:
 if ( options === null || optionsType === 'number'  ) {
to
 if ( options === null || optionsType === 'number' || options === undefined ) {
seems to work ok

Comment: just tried https://raw.github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/stock2/js/highstock.src.js and now the bar chart orientation is column oriented